# Updating part of a shared variable in Theano

Tags: python, neural-network, theano

How to update part of a shared variable in Theano?

E.g. instead of doing:

```
gradient_W = T.grad(cost,W)
updates.append((W, W-learning_rate*gradient_W))
train = th.function(inputs=[index], outputs=[cost], updates=updates,
                            givens={x:self.X[index:index+mini_batch_size,:]})
```

I'd like to only update part of `W`, e.g. only the first column:

```
 updates.append((W[:, 0], W[:, 0]-learning_rate*gradient_W))
```

But doing so gives the error `TypeError: ('update target must be a SharedVariable', Subtensor{::, int64}.0)`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ae.py", line 330, in <module>
    main()
  File "ae.py", line 305, in main
    ae.train(n_epochs=n_epochs, mini_batch_size=100, learning_rate=0.002, train_data= train_sentence_embeddings, test_data= test_sentence_embeddings)
  File "ae.py", line 87, in train
    givens={x:self.X[index:index+mini_batch_size,:]})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/compile/function.py", line 266, in function
    profile=profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 489, in pfunc
    no_default_updates=no_default_updates)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 194, in rebuild_collect_shared
    store_into)
TypeError: ('update target must be a SharedVariable', Subtensor{::, int64}.0)
```

What is the typical way to do so in Theano?

`W` is a typical weight matrix:

```
initial_W = np.asarray(rng.uniform(
                 low=-4 * np.sqrt(6. / (self.hidden_size + self.n)),
                 high=4 * np.sqrt(6. / (self.hidden_size + self.n)),
                 size=(self.n, self.hidden_size)), dtype=th.config.floatX)
W = th.shared(value=initial_W, name='W', borrow=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use e.g. `theano.tensor.set_subtensor`.

Taking the updates line you mention above, this becomes:

```
updates.append((W, T.set_subtensor(W[:, 0], W[:, 0]-learning_rate*gradient_W)))
```

where `T = theano.tensor`.

Another possibility, a little more concise in your case, is `T.inc_subtensor`, where you specify only the increment instead of the new value:

```
updates.append((W, T.inc_subtensor(W[:, 0], -learning_rate*gradient_W)))
```

Comment: Please make sure that in your code `learning_rate * gradient_W` actually has the right shape. If it is the gradient for full `W`, you will have to slice it as well.

Comment: Thanks, I find your answer better than the one I've just stumbled upon in the FAQ (http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/faq_tutorial.html, the question is actually the only question in the FAQ), as in the FAQ  the `cost` has to be expressed in terms of the subtensor.