# Theano: this shared variable already has an update expression

Tags: python, neural-network, theano

Is there any way to define more than one update on the same share variable when calling `theano.function()`?

Example:

```
updates = []
updates.append([(self.W, self.W - 1)])
updates.append([(self.W, self.W - 2)])
train = th.function(inputs=[index], outputs=[cost], updates=updates)
```

will throw the error `this shared variable already has an update expression`:

```
ignore_bug_before` to at least "0.7".
  tolerate_inplace_aliasing=tolerate_inplace_aliasing)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ae.py", line 340, in <module>
    main()
  File "ae.py", line 315, in main
    ae.train(n_epochs=n_epochs, mini_batch_size=100, learning_rate=0.002, train_data= train_sentence_embeddings, test_data= test_sentence_embeddings)
  File "ae.py", line 97, in train
    givens={x:self.X[index:index+mini_batch_size,:]})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/compile/function.py", line 266, in function
    profile=profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 489, in pfunc
    no_default_updates=no_default_updates)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 198, in rebuild_collect_shared
    (store_into, update_d[store_into]))
ValueError: ('this shared variable already has an update expression', (W, DimShuffle{1,0}.0))
```

I was interested in doing so as I have weight matrix that I need to update in such a way that different parts of it has a different update (which I do it using [`set_subtensor`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33921398/395857)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/theano-users/L6Efhjj4YOE) on the theano-users mailing list...

You need to chain the `set_subtensor`s so that you only end up with a single entry for the whole tensor in the updates list.

For example (code not like original because original does not actually include set_subtensor anywhere):

```
new_w = self.W
new_W = theano.tensor.set_subtensor(new_W[0], -1)
new_W = theano.tensor.set_subtensor(new_W[1], -2)
updates = [(self.W, new_W)]
train = theano.function(inputs=[index], outputs=[cost], updates=updates)
```